# Header title on Pivot/Panorama Wp8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

[image: Twitter Example]

How do i get icons beside header title. Example is the twitter app on WP8 above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd make a custom font for the title, taking an old font and ripping a char and putting your custom one in. This would only be used for the title.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but I was asking about the Icon beside the name. How do i get an icon of my choice there?

Comment: Add make a vector of the char and add it to a font! :P I don't know how to do it any other way, sorry.

Comment: Thanks.. but I got an easier way. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom [`HeaderTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.headertemplate%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which will show an icon instead of header text:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="Altered Styles">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>  
        <!-- This changes to look of the items headers -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- show image here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

You can do this with `Panorama` control as well.

Comment: Hey @MarcinJuraszek I tried and it works great. However, i see that whatever i put in <!-- show image here --> is repeated for all the PivotItems. How can i have a home image in header for 1st PivotItem and @ Image for PivotItem 2 ?